# Problem saving a new item to custom SharePoint 2007 list using Silverlight 4 UI control

Tags: silverlight-4.0, sharepoint-2007, xelement

I am hoping someone might be able to help me. I'm working on a Contact Manager built using a custom SharePoint 2007 list with a Silverlight 4 UI embedded in a content editor web part.

I am currently able to retrieve the data from the list and display it in a datagrid on the UI and everything works well.

Now I am trying to add the the ability to add new items to the list using the following code but the items do not save.

I've remotely debugged the following code using the Debug -> Attach to Process option and everything seems to execute successful without any errors but it does not save the item to SharePoint.

In order to simplify and get a working insert function I changed all the SharePoint fieds to single line text with the exception of the notes (multiline) and none of the fileds are required.

The sharepoint site does require Windows authentication but it seems to be working correctly as I am able to display it as well as add new items manually using the standard SharePoint forms.

Lastly, I have added the xml for the Batch element at the bottom which I copied as output while debuging.

Please let me know if there is any additional information I might be missing.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you might be willing to provide.

Charles

```
public string sharepoint_soap_namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/";
public string sharepoint_rowset_namespace = "#RowsetSchema";
public string service_lists_url = "http://myDomain/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
public string listName = "MyContacts";

 public void TestCreateContact()
{
  Uri serviceUri = new Uri(service_lists_url);
  BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
  binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647; // This has to be the same as in the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file.
  EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(serviceUri);
  ListsSoapClient testCreateClient = new ListsSoapClient(binding, endpoint);

XElement batch = new XElement("batch",
  new XElement("Method",
  new XAttribute("ID", "1"),
  new XAttribute("Cmd", "New"),
  CreateFieldElement("ows_ID", "New"),
  CreateFieldElement("ows_Title", "John"),
  CreateFieldElement("ows_SupportFor","USA"),
  CreateFieldElement("ows_LastName","Doe")
));


testCreateClient.UpdateListItemsCompleted +=
      new EventHandler<UpdateListItemsCompletedEventArgs>(createSoapClient_UpdateListItemsCompletedEventArgs);

testCreateClient.UpdateListItemsAsync(listName, batch);
testCreateClient.CloseAsync();

}


private XElement CreateFieldElement(string fieldName, string fieldValue)
{
  XElement element = new XElement("Field",
  new XAttribute("Name", fieldName),
  fieldValue);
  return element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick update to let everyone know I was able to answer my own question.
It seems that in the batch XElement I was using the wrong field names.

> CreateFieldElement("ows_SupportFor","USA"),

I was using "ows_SupportFor" instead of "SupportFor" without the "ows_" prefix.

Cheers,
Charles